# Cloudflare workers CORS ignored

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I created a SendGrid form using CF Workers and set (for testing) Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*' but it's being ignored on the frontend:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<domain>.workers.dev/' from origin 'https://<frontend-domain>.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Do I need to also add it to the AXIOS `POST` request?

Here's code from my workers file:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS");
  myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400",);
  return new Response((emailResponse.ok), {status: 200, headers: myHeaders})
```

And here's the AXIOS request:

```
this.$axios.$post(
  "https://<domain>.workers.dev/",
  {
    name: this.mailData.name,
    eMail: this.mailData.eMail,
    phone: this.mailData.phone,
    message: this.mailData.message,
  },
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);
```

It all works fine using Insomnia and the headers are visible there:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've correctly set the headers on the response to the `POST` itself. However, before the browser even sends the `POST`, it uses a "preflight request" to check whether cross-origin `POST`s are allowed. The preflight request is an `OPTIONS` request, using the same URL. You will need to respond to `OPTIONS` requests as well, with the same access control headers, and status code 204 (no content).

See [the MDN documentation on preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Alternatively, if your application will accept the `POST` request using `Content-Type: text/plain` instead of `Content-Type: application/json`, then that will avoid the need for a preflight request, because `Content-Type: text/plain` qualifies as a ["Simple Request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) and therefore does not require a preflight.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering what Preflight is but didn't bother to check it out. Usually when working with steady frameworks it happens automatically so I've never wondered about it. Handling the OPTIONS request fixed everything. Cheers!